# Using Promises to call function inside another function with Bluebird promises library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 `Node Js` functions. What I'm trying to do here is, I want to call `normalizeFilePath` and get the normalized path, after that check whether a file exist or not with that `normalizedFilePath` and after all these, create a file if the file doesn't already exist. This is the first day of using promises (Bluebird) and I'm new to `Node JS` and `Java Script`. Below code structure is getting complex. Of course this is not a good idea at all.

```
var createProjectFolder = function (projectName) {

};


var checkFileExistance = function (filePath) {
  return new promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    normalizeFilePath(filePath).then(function (normalizedFilePath) {
      return fs.existSync(normalizedFilePath);
    });
  })

};

var normalizeFilePath = function (filePath) {
  return new promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(path.normalize(filePath));
  });
};
```

How can i manage promises to implement that concept?

Comment: Why are you not simply inject the callback (resolve and reject function) into each child function? E.g. function() { return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { doSomethingOtherAsync(resolve, reject); }); }? Are you searching for simply a working or the "best" solution?

Comment: the best solution actually

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's improve your code in two simple steps.

### Promises are meant for async functions

As long as `path.normalize` is synchronous, it should not be wrapped in promise.

So it can be as simple as that.

```
var normalizeFilePath = function (filePath) {
  return path.normalize(filePath);
};
```

But for now lets *pretend* that `path.normalize` is async, so we can use your version.

```
var normalizeFilePath = function (filePath) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve( path.normalize(filePath) );
  });
};
```

### Promisify all the things

Sync is bad. Sync blocks event loop. So, instead of `fs.existsSync` we will use `fs.exists`.

```
var checkFileExistance = function (filePath) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.exists(filePath, function (exists) {
      resolve(exists);
    });
  });
};
```

As You can see, we are wrapping async function that accepts a callback with a promise. It's quite a common concept to "promisify" a function, so we could use a [library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) for that. Or even use [fs-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promise), that is -- you guess it -- `fs` with promises.

### Chaining promises

Now, what we want is making three actions one after another:

1. Normalize file path
2. Check if file already exists
3. If not, create a directory

Keeping that in mind, our main function can look like this.

```
var createProjectFolder = function (projectName) {
    normalizeFilePath(projectName)
      .then(checkFileExistance)
      .then(function (exists) {
        if (!exists) {
          // create folder
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // if there are any errors in promise chain
        // we can catch them in one place, yay!
      });
};
```

Don't forget to add the `catch` call so you would not miss any errors.